# Programmatically update entry field

Tags: entry, entries-field, validation

I'm trying to update an entry's field value from a Craft plugin. First I was trying to just update the attributes of the entry like so:

```
$entry->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
  'metaStatus' => 'Declined'
));

craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

But that wouldn't work because `getContent` doesn't return the data needed in order for the `EntryModel` to pass validation. The next solution was to loop through each of the fields and grab their field value like so:

```
$fields = array();

foreach($entry->getFieldLayout()->getFields() as $layout) {
  $handle = $layout->getField()->handle;

  $fields[$handle] = $entry->getFieldValue($handle);
}

$fields['metaStatus'] = 'Declined';

$entry->setContent($fields);

craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry); // FAIL
```

*Now* I'm having issues with matrix/asset fields validating since they come back as empty. Am I going to have to look for matrix/asset fields in my loop above and correctly format the data? There must be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Related question answered by Brandon Kelly: [Categories field is losing its value when programmatically updating other fields’ values](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/11146/125)

Answer (score 6):

I got around this issue by looping through all fields that were of BaseElementFieldType re-setting them to their current value.

```php
$fields = $entry->getFieldLayout()->getFields();

$referentialFields = array();
foreach ($fields as $layoutField) {
  $field = $layoutField->getField();
  if ($field->getFieldType() instanceof BaseElementFieldType) {
    $referentialFields[$field->handle] = $entry->{$field->handle}->ids();
  }
}

$entry->setContentFromPost(array_merge($referentialFields, array(
  'yourField' => 'yourValue'
)));

craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're very close. Try this:

```
$entry->getContent()->setAttribute('metaStatus', 'Declined');
craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still fails validation – required fields still complain.

Comment: But is this an entry that has already been saved and has validated? Or is it a new entry?

Comment: It's already been saved, I'm retrieving it like so:  `$entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($entryId);`. All of the other fields except for the matrix/asset/entry fields are pre-filled with the `getContent` method so I assume this is just a Craft bug...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure of the technical reasons (I guess something to do with relation fields not have a column in the `craft_content` table), but you also need to re-save the existing ids for any relation fields (Assets, Entries, Categories, Matrix, etc) before the element can be saved:

```
$entry->setContentFromPost(array(
    'metaStatus'  => 'Declined',
    'assetsField' => $entry->assetsField->ids(),
    'matrixField' => $entry->matrixField->ids(),
);

craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Craft 3**

```php
$entry->setFieldValue('my_field_handle', 'new_value');
$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
```